# Runtime.exec() from tomcat6 succeeds, but cannot access any files

Tags: java, permissions, debian, tomcat6, runtime.exec

I'm moving our servlets (pure Java, running in Tomcat 6) from CentOS to Debian, and faced the problem with executing commands with `Runtime.exec()`.
(The command should be ImageMagick's `convert` in production, but I have simplified the calls to find the source of problems, so all the following code with `echo` is tested and not working as well).

```
String command = "echo test123 > /tmp/tomcat6-tmp/1";
Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
Process process = runtime.exec(command);
int exitVal = process.waitFor();
```

Seems to be pretty common way to call an external program. It does run, returns `0` in `exitVal`, but fails to create file and put text in it.
So does low-level approach:

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("echo", "test123 > /tmp/tomcat6-tmp/3");
Process process = pb.start();
int resInt = process.waitFor();
```

But  it **is** possible to create a file and put some text in it using Java code placed in the same method:

```
String fname = "/tmp/tomcat6-tmp/2";
File file = new File(fname);
file.createNewFile();
FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(file);
fileWriter.write("test123");
fileWriter.close();
```

`Runtime.exec("whoami")` successfully returns `tomcat6`, the folder `/tmp/tomcat6-tmp/` does exist, all permissions are set correctly.

```
$ ls -al /tmp/tomcat6-tmp/
total 60
drwxr-xr-x 2 tomcat6 root     4096 Mar  2 15:26 .
drwxrwxrwt 6 root    root     4096 Mar  2 15:25 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 tomcat6 tomcat6     7 Mar  2 15:26 2
```

All commands without need to access files in system are seem to execute normally with `Runtime.exec()` in the same context.

I use fresh install of debian squeeze with tomcat6 installed from packages, without any modifications in configuration:

```
$ aptitude show tomcat6
Package: tomcat6                         
State: installed
Version: 6.0.28-9+squeeze1
.....
$ cat /etc/issue
Debian GNU/Linux 6.0 \n \l
```

How can I solve the issue?
Or at least where should I look? I've googled every imaginable reason for Java to misbehave this way, but failed to find a clue.

**P.S.** As this is default installation, Java security manager is disabled in `/etc/init.d/tomcat6`

```
# Use the Java security manager? (yes/no)
TOMCAT6_SECURITY=no
```

Comment: I had a similar issue with rails and CentOS. The problem was SELinux, so there's a chance that the user that runs tomcat doesn't have permissions to open a shell or run that command. I had to disable SELinux completely to make it work (this is not a good idea in general, but it was in a local VM where I was doing some testing, so it didn't really matter). SELinux is also bundled in Debian, but I don't know if it's active by default.

Comment: No, SELinux was disabled. The problem was in different way of parsing commandline in Runtime.exec() and in bash.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the action you want into a single executable shell script, then `exec` the shell script.

Java's `Runtime.exec()` is a wrapper around the `exec` system call, which will run the process directly, rather than under a sub-shell. The `>` redirection is carried out by the shell, and will not work as an argument to a directly `exec`ed process.

Comment: Thank you. 
I was inattentive during my tests, and mixed two problems in parameters to Runtime.exec()  


I've separated them thanks to your clue, and solved both.

Comment: @kirushik can you please write the Java code that solved your problem? I have the same problem and I really need to solve it. Thanks!

Comment: @Jairo simply use Runtime.exec without protective symbols (you won't have any pipe, redirections and all that shell-specific stuff). And use http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec(java.lang.String[]) to pass arguments to the command (one-by-one, in array of Strings)

Answer (score 1):

Don't know if this "echo test123 > /tmp/tomcat6-tmp/1" can be run as one command. I remember that I had similar problem and I had to split it, so try to run "echo test123" and then obtain an input stream with the output of the command. If you have a stream you can easily write to file.

Moreover, you execute command with args so try to use method that takes array as a parameter.