# Run C++ program using Java

Tags: java, c++, linux, command-line

I created a Java program that will process files using a C++ program. This is the part of the code that calls the C++ program:

```
public static boolean buildPAKFile(String OSMFile){

        log("Starting building PAK file for " + OSMFile + "...");

        // get name of OSMFile
        String[] OSMFileName = OSMFile.split("\\.");

        try {
            Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
            Process pr = rt.exec("cat " + OSMFile + " | ../gosmore rebuild " + OSMFileName[0]);

            /*
            BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(pr.getInputStream()));

            String line=null;

            while((line=input.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(line);
            }*/

            int exitVal = pr.waitFor();
            System.out.println("Exited with error code "+exitVal);

        } catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.toString());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        log("Done building PAK File for " + OSMFile);

        return true;

    }
```

When I uncomment the part the prints the input stream from the C++ program, gibberish text appears. How can I do this properly? Thanks!

Added:

This is an example of the command executed:

```
cat ncr-sample.osm | ../gosmore rebuild ncr-sample.pak

Building ncr-sample.pak using style /usr/local/share/gosmore/elemstyles.xml...
../gosmore is in the public domain and comes without warranty

...
484 for (pairs = 0; pairs < PAIRS && s2grp < S2GROUP (0) + S2GROUPS; )
485 for (pairs = 0; pairs < PAIRS && s2grp < S2GROUP (0) + S2GROUPS; )
486 for (pairs = 0; pairs < PAIRS && s2grp < S2GROUP (0) + S2GROUPS; )
487 for (pairs = 0; pairs < PAIRS && s2grp < S2GROUP (0) + S2GROUPS; )
488 for (pairs = 0; pairs < PAIRS && s2grp < S2GROUP (0) + S2GROUPS; )
489 for (pairs = 0; pairs < PAIRS && s2grp < S2GROUP (0) + S2GROUPS; )
490 for (pairs = 0; pairs < PAIRS && s2grp < S2GROUP (0) + S2GROUPS; )
491 for (ndType *ndItr = ndBase; ndItr < ndBase + hashTable[bucketsMin1 + 1]; ndItr++)
492 qsort (&lseg[0], lseg.size () / 2, sizeof (lseg[0]) * 2, (int (*)(const void *, const void *))HalfSegCmp)
493 for (int i = 0; i < IDXGROUPS; i++)
Icon public.png not found
Icon public.png not found
Icon religion/synagogue.png not found
Icon religion/mosque.png not found
Icon rendering/landuse/cemetery.png not found
Icon wlan.png not found
Icon rendering/landuse/cemetery.png not found
../gosmore is in the public domain and comes without warranty
```

Comment: try: 
    `PrintStream out = new PrintStream(System.out, true, "UTF-8");

    out.println(line);` this will force the encoding to be UTF-8.. you can try different encoding as well.

Comment: What does the C++ program output when you run it outside of your Java code?

Comment: @Matt the complete command is "cat file.osm | ../gosmore rebuild file.pak". This command passes the the contents to the 'gosmore' app, which in turn rebuilds it ('rebuild' parameter) to form a PAK file with the name file.pak.

Comment: ...but what does that **output** (specifically, **to stdout**) when executed?

Comment: @Matt it prints the on-going process of the c++ program. After that, the PAK file is produced.

Comment: Please, could you be more specific? Does it print something like a progress bar? Does it use something like ncurses to produce fancy output? Are you including the call to `cat`? An example (copy it into your question) would be extremely helpful.

Comment: @Matt I'm sorry. I was confused with your previous question. When this command is executed, it prints lines that shows the progress of the operations. The output will be then a new file. Is that what you're asking?

Comment: When you call `Process#getInputStream()` and read from it, you are reading whatever that process prints to stdout (the console). When you execute the code equivalent to `cat " + OSMFile + " | ../gosmore rebuild " + OSMFileName[0]` in a shell (aka console, outside of your Java program), what gets printed to stdout?

Comment: @Matt the progress of the process.

Comment: That is still **way too vague**. Could you _please_ just copy-and-paste an example of this into your question?

Comment: @Jairo: Do a `cat file.osm | ../gosmore rebuild file.pak > output.txt`, and put the contents of output.txt in your question. I think the "gibberish" is already there.

Comment: @Paulo I had tried that. What it prints is this part only "Building ncr-sample.pak using style /usr/local/share/gosmore/elemstyles.xml...
../gosmore is in the public domain and comes without warranty". The next lines are not printed in the output.txt.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found out with the help of @Adrian Cox that the correct implementation should be like this:

```
String gosmoreCmd = " cat " + OSMFile + " | ../gosmore rebuild"     
                    + OSMFileName[0] + ".pak";
String[] cmds = {"/bin/bash", "-c", gosmoreCmd};
Process pr = rt.exec(cmds);
```

/bin/bash runs the shell, which with the **-c** parameter, you can able to pass a new command to this shell.

Answer (score 3):

I've seen [this before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5168806/runtime-exec-from-tomcat6-succeeds-but-cannot-access-any-files/5169242#5169242).  `Runtime.exec()` does not spawn a shell, so cannot process shell redirection characters such as `|`. The only command you are running is the initial `cat`. To fix this, either pass the XML file into the standard input of the subprocess, or wrap the chain into a shell script.

Comment: what do you mean by "either pass the XML file into the standard input of the subprocess" ? If I wrap the command to a shell scipt? can I pass arguments there?

Comment: I don't know much about `gosmore`, and whether you can persuade it to accept input via another means. You're currently running a shell pipeline that uses the `cat` command to read the XML file and write it to the standard input of `gosmore`. Your Java code could instead read the data from `OSMFile` and write it to `pr.getOutputStream()`.

Comment: Here's a different example, which explicitly uses a sub-shell to handle the piping: http://www.devdaily.com/java/java-exec-system-command-pipeline-pipe

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I would like to check it but I need a clearer answer, for the benefit of those who will read this page. But I +1 it. I'll try to put my own answer here (based on what I found out).